# Johnson's Theorem - Proof (Runde) Clarification

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis, amenability

I am reading Runde's Lectures on Amenability. In the proof of Johnson's theorem where he proves "$L^{1}(G)$ is amenable Banach algebra implies $G$ is amenable" : he defines a $L^1(G)$ bimodule action on $L^\infty(G)$. With the help of this action, he gets finally a $\tilde{m} \in L^\infty(G)^*$ such that $$ \langle \delta_g * \phi,\tilde{m} \rangle = \langle \phi,\tilde{m} \rangle \quad (g \in G,\phi \in L^\infty(G)).$$

Then he claims $|\tilde{m}| \neq 0$ is left invariant and $\langle 1,|\tilde{m}|\rangle^{-1}|\tilde{m}|$ is a left invariant mean. I don't understand this part.

I posted this question in MSE. The post was receiving downvotes but no response. So I deleted it.

Comment: I think this should be asked in MSE.

Comment: @user89334 People hardly answers question related to amenability in MSE nowadays

Comment: @user89334 I posted it in MSE. The post is receiving downvotes now.

Comment: Mamabo, I think that if you include a phrase as "this was posted a few days ago in MSE and received no attention" and add a link people will be less likely to downvote.

Comment: @user89334 I just posted this question in MSE providing this page MO link. I have posted some other questions related to amenability which didn't receive any answers. That's why. Sorry if I am wasting your time.

Comment: Mambo, maybe it's not clear what is it that you don't understand. Is it the claim $|\tilde{m}|\neq 0$? The construction of $\tilde{m}$?

Comment: @user89334 I understand the construction of $\tilde{m}$. I don't understand how he gets a left invariant mean from $\tilde{m}$.

Comment: Do ou undertand that $\langle \delta_g*\phi,\tilde{m}\rangle=\langle \phi,g^{-1}\tilde{m}\rangle$?

Comment: @user89334 Are you speaking about $L^{\infty}(G)^*$ being a $G$-module or something else? I don't know about $G$-modules. Here $L^{\infty}(G)^*$ is treated as $L^1(G)$-bimodule. Can't we show that without going into $G$-module business? I guess Johnson's paper use $G$-modules.

Comment: I understand the left invariance of $\tilde{m}$. How is he bringing it as a finitely additive positive measure on $G$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39040/discussion-between-mambo-and-user89334).

Comment: Mambo: I should point out that there is sometimes confusion/ambiguity about what is meant by a mean. The part of Johnson's proof that you seem happy with allow one to produce a left-invariant bounded functional on $L^\infty(G)$. It seems that what you are asking is how one then obtains a left-invariant _state_ on $L^\infty(G)$, i.e. we need positivity. Have I understood your question correctly

Comment: @user89334 While I agree that the question is a bit basic for the current form of MathOverflow, I am no longer on MSE, and it seems that the pool of people who use MSE and who have experience on amenability of Banach algebras is rather small. So there is a case that questions in that area could be considered for re-asking here, _if they do not receive adequate attention on MSE_

Comment: On a different topic: Mambo, you should make it clear on http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1745237/does-fourier-algebra-of-locally-compact-group-separate-compact-sets-of-the-group that the question now has an answer on MathOverflow, and provide a link to that answer

Comment: @YemonChoi Yes, you have understood my question.

Comment: Having talked with you in chat, I am now confused by your claim that "I understand that if m is a left invariant finitely additive measure on a group G, then |m| is also a left invariant measure." If you understand this, then you have answered your own question

Comment: @YemonChoi I told that with respect to total variation norm.

Comment: @YemonChoi I removed it